# Racket Scalar-Vector Multiplication

Tags: racket

I was trying to make a function that does scalar to vector multiplication using map, but doesn't seem to work.

```
(define (f k m)
  (map (lambda (x) (map * k x)) m))
```

Example usage would be `(f 2 '((1 2 3) (4 5 6) (7 8 9)))` which would give `'((2 4 6) (8 10 12) (14 16 18))`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are near the solution, which requires *two* `map`s, since you have a list of lists:

```
(define (f k m)
  (map (lambda (x) 
           (map (lambda (y) (* k y))
                x))
       m))

(f 2 '((1 2 3) (4 5 6) (7 8 9)))
; => '((2 4 6) (8 10 12) (14 16 18))
```

Comment: or with more suggestive naming, `(map (lambda (xs) (map (lambda (x) (* k x)) xs)) m)`. :)